# Newbe, MySQL query skips first entry - no duplicate fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

trying to get my head around this MySQL jibberish, lol - now I do not normally ask for help but on this one I think I do need a shove.

I have searched for the answers to this however the solutions are all based around the askers duplication of the **fetch_array command**, however I have not done this but still this code skips the first entry.

Can someone point out what I have done here that causes this to skip...?

code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','person','password', 'database'); // connect to database 
if (!$link) { die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); }   // problem, then die

$sql = "SELECT * FROM id_info_db"; // Query construct
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);  //query action

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {    // print out rows
        echo "User: " . $row["username"]. " - Password: " . $row["password"]. " " . $row["email"]. "<br>"; }

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Can't see how this would skip a row, unless the containing html you're dumping into this two would somehow cause the first row's display to be supressed. have you done a "view source" to see what html was actually received?

Comment: How do you know it skips an entry? Why would it be the first one? Your query isn't ordered.

Comment: how do you know what is "first" with out an order by you cant know

Comment: It looks like it should work for the most part, but you can always try `mysqli_data_seek ( $result , 0 ); ` to return to the 'first' result and see what it is compared to what you're getting.

Comment: Have you tried running `mysqli_num_rows` on the result to see if it returns the same number as you have entries in your database?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I had a loose **/body** tag at the end? why I don't know but it generated this result. Now I have deleted it the output is correct. 
A remnant that should have been deleted that throws up an unfathomable error. Lol